# Android: OnClick play random .mp3 from /res/raw file

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, filenotfoundexception

I am fairly new to Android Application development, and I'm trying to play a random .mp3 from the /res/raw folder.

**FIXED** I have this so far, but I came across a FileNotFoundException.

**FIXED** Only plays a random sound on first click, after that it is the same sound unless reopen the app.

**NEW ISSUE** Now plays random sounds, but when I click the button multiple times the sounds start playing at the same time and still getting the "start() mUri is null" message in the logs.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
MediaPlayer player;
int soundIndex;
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


/**
 * gets a random index from an array of sounds
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int getRandomSoundIndex(){

    int soundIndex;
    int[] sound = SOUNDZ;

    Random random = new Random();
    soundIndex = random.nextInt(sound.length);

    return sound[soundIndex];
}

/**
 * Plays that random sound on button click
 * @param button
 */
public void playRandomSound(View button){

    //where button is physically located
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //get random sound index
    soundIndex = getRandomSoundIndex();

    //make media player
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundIndex);

    //play sound
    player.start();

}
```

Here is the log:

---

09-21 17:42:32.528: D/MediaPlayer(4282): start() mUri is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

First, calling `toString()` on a `Field` will give you a string representation of the object instance, such as `"public static final int com.lena.button.R$raw.laptopkeyboard1"`, which is not very useful. Presumably, you want `getInt()`.

Second, a raw resource is not an asset, and so you do not use `openFd()`. Instead, use the static `create()` method to create your `MediaPlayer` instance, passing in the `int` you get from `getInt()` on your `Field`.

Third, reflection is slow. Please do not do it more than once. Use `R.raw.class.getFields()` *once*, caching the results. Or, better yet, consider not using reflection at all, and instead using your own literal Java `int[]`:

```
static int[] SOUNDZ={R.raw.boom, R.raw.chaka, R.raw.laka};
```

(substituting in your own sound resources, of course)

Comment: Thank you! I got it to play a random sound on the first click using my own literal Java int[]

Now when I click the button again, it plays the same sound.  Is there a way to reset the button click?

Comment: In the logs it says "MediaPlayer(4282): start() mUri is null"  What does that mean?

Comment: @LenaSanch: "Is there a way to reset the button click?" -- `create()` a new `MediaPlayer`, AFAIK.